# How to nicely format a table including measurement errors

Tags: tables

I have a table which contains measurement results. Currently I have one column per measurement 'type'. In each column, I have values like `$+$0.74\,\,$\pm$\,\,0.14`. The table is rather long (~30 rows), and looks very unorganized. I think it is possible to align the column on *one* character, like the (first?) `.`, or the `$\pm$`. However, I think that then it still looks unorganized. Is there a way to align table columns on more than one item, like both `.` *and* the `$\pm$`. Maybe this will also look weird, I don't know.

Here is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccccl}
 & A & B & C & D & E\\
continental US      & $-$0.81\,$\pm$\,0.14 & $-$1.7\,$\pm$\,0.30 & $-$0.81\,$\pm$\,0.15 & $-$1.6\,$\pm$\,0.30 & $-$0.78 \\
Central-Eastern US  & $-$2.9\,$\pm$\,0.38  & $-$3.0\,$\pm$\,0.38 & $-$2.9\,$\pm$\,0.39  & $-$2.9\,$\pm$\,0.39 & $-$2.7  \\
Western Europe      & $-$2.9\,$\pm$\,0.63  & $-$2.6\,$\pm$\,0.56 & $-$3.0\,$\pm$\,0.65  & $-$2.6\,$\pm$\,0.56 & $-$2.6  \\
Japan               & $-$0.49\,$\pm$\,0.13 & $-$1.2\,$\pm$\,0.33 & $-$0.49\,$\pm$\,0.14 & $-$1.2\,$\pm$\,0.33 & $-$0.49 \\
Middle East         & $+$0.78\,$\pm$\,0.08 & $+$4.0\,$\pm$\,0.42 & $+$0.79\,$\pm$\,0.08 & $+$4.0\,$\pm$\,0.42 & $+$0.72 \\
East Central China  & $+$10\,$\pm$\,1.1    & $+$21\,$\pm$\,2.2   & $+$10\,$\pm$\,1.1    & $+$20\,$\pm$\,2.2   & $+$8.7  \\
North Central India & $+$1.3\,$\pm$\,0.27  & $+$4.0\,$\pm$\,0.84 & ~~1.1\,$\pm$\,0.27   & $+$4.6\,$\pm$\,1.1  & $+$1.1  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions to make this nicer are welcome :)

Comment: `siunitx` allows you to align number in tables. Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85769/align-numbers-and-separated-uncertainties-in-tables-with-s-columns

Comment: What do the "measurements" represent? If you were to read the table aloud to me, how would you read it column-wise or row-wise?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides *measurements* are trends in air quality. rows are locations, columns are different methods. If reading the table, I would read row-wise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend `siunitx` for this kind of table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

% uncertainty is separated with a "plus-minus" symbol
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=-1.2,
   table-figures-uncertainty=1]
 S[table-format=-1.2,
   table-figures-uncertainty=1]
}
\toprule
 & {A} & {B} \\
\midrule
continental US      & -0.81 \pm 0.14 & -1.7 \pm 0.30 \\
Central-Eastern US  & -2.9  \pm 0.38 & -3.0 \pm 0.38 \\
Western Europe      & -2.9  \pm 0.63 & -2.6 \pm 0.56 \\
Japan               & -0.49 \pm 0.13 & -1.2 \pm 0.33 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The same number of significant digits seems better; look at the package documentation for more details.

[image]

Comment: nice one! thanks! any idea how I can do this in LyX?

Comment: @andreas-h No, I've never used LyX: I tried it once, five minutes later there was no trace of it on my machine any more. I think it's false that it eases using LaTeX; to the contrary, it makes easy things like this difficult.

Comment: The only reason I'm using LyX is to be able to share documents and annotate (like in collaborative writing) them in a group of people. LyX allows you to insert notes, track changes, etc. I personally would do this in plain LaTeX with git, but some of my coworkers (read: boss) refuse to use a plain text file in an ASCII editor for this. They're used to word, and I'm glad I can convince them to use LyX ... Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to insert it as ERT. You can then put a preview box around it so the rendered table will show up. Or you could save it in an external file and include it (Insert File > Child Document)

Comment: @egreg I agree that the same number of significant digits *looks* better. But strictly speaking, it's not correct, right? Writing `2.90` implies that the value is measured to three significant digits, when in fact it's only two. At least, that's how I learned it.

Comment: @andreas-h Homogeneous data in a table should be measured with the same precision or the reader should be explicitly warned it isn't. In any case, the error has *two* decimal digits, so also the average value should have.