# How to left-align captions when table is centred?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I found here on stack exchange some ideas how to do this. However, there is something wrong with my approach. I did the following:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
```

The idea for the next two lines is from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98332/how-to-nicely-format-a-table-including-measurement-errors). This helps me to write values and their standard-deviation in a nice way.

```
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}


\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{Caption of my Table}
\begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=-1.3,
table-figures-uncertainty=1]
S[table-format=-1.3,
table-figures-uncertainty=1]
}
\toprule
& {Sensitivity} & {Specificity} & {BACC}& {Threshold} \\
\midrule
Full     & 0.555 \pm 0.118      & 0.924  \pm 0.028  & 0.738 \pm 0.059   &                0.235  \pm 0.029   \\
 AIC    & 0.560  \pm 0.110     & 0.927 \pm 0.029   & 0.743 \pm 0.054   &      0.234  \pm 0.030   \\
 BIC     & 0.527 \pm 0.126      & 0.924  \pm 0.033   & 0.725 \pm 0.068 &  0.231  \pm 0.031   \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:perflogcross}
\end{table}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The caption is left-aligned but not on top of the table. It looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please make your MWE complete by adding all the packages in one code, not code snippets. Your code is giving me errors right from the start.

Comment: also: "The caption is left-aligned but not on top the table" do you want the caption to align with the table? because it certainly is _above_ the table

Comment: Thanks for the question. Sorry that was not precise at all. Yes, I'd like to have the caption to align with the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable,caption}

\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Caption of my Table}\label{tab:perflogcross}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=-1.3,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
  S[table-format=-1.3,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
  S[table-format=-1.3,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
  S[table-format=-1.3,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
}
\toprule
& {Sensitivity} & {Specificity} & {BACC}& {Threshold} \\
\midrule
Full & 0.555 \pm 0.118 & 0.924 \pm 0.028 & 0.738 \pm 0.059 & 0.235 \pm 0.029 \\
AIC  & 0.560 \pm 0.110 & 0.927 \pm 0.029 & 0.743 \pm 0.054 & 0.234 \pm 0.030 \\
BIC  & 0.527 \pm 0.126 & 0.924 \pm 0.033 & 0.725 \pm 0.068 & 0.231 \pm 0.031 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. That works perfect! Thank you for the quick reply.