# Align elements in tabular like align environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

in this table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tabular}{rcc}
    \hline
    Text 1  & $6,58\pm0,45$     & $6,94\pm0,51$\bigstrut[t]\\
    Text 2  & $25\pm1$          & $29\pm3$\\
    Text 3  & $8,16\pm 2,23$    & $11,01\pm1,93$\\
    Text 4  & $60\pm 14$        & $148\pm8$\\
    Text 5  & $90,7\pm 2,5$     & $109,2\pm3,8$\\
    Text 6  & $0,030\pm 0,008$  & $0,034\pm0,004$\\
    Text 7  & $5,72\pm 0,66$    & $143,47\pm38,47 $\\
    Text 8  & --                & $(10,81\pm1,19)\times10^{5}$\\
    Text 9  & --                & $‑12,95\pm 0,35$\bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I align the elements in columns 2 and 3 by the `\pm` symbol. I'd like to have all the `\pm` symbols aligned in the center

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

In my view, aligning the numbers before and after the `\pm` symbols on their respective decimal markers is at least as important as aligning the `\pm` symbols. To achieve the former objective, I suggest you use the `dcolumn` package. (That way, you will also avoid the excessive spacing after the commas that serve as the decimal markers.) To achieve the latter, simply place the `\pm` directives in separate columns.

Incidentally, the "minus" symbol in the final row of your tabular environment isn't an ASCII symbol; I've replaced it with `-` (simple dash) to that TeX can generate a mathematical minus symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{array,dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{,}{#1}} % numbers aligned on decimal commas
\newcolumntype{C}{>{${}}c<{{}$}}  % for columns that house "\pm" symbols
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{2.3}@{}C@{}d{2.3} d{3.3}@{}C@{}d{2.6}}
    \toprule
    Text 1  & 6,58&\pm&0,45     & 6,94&\pm&0,51\\
    Text 2  & 25&\pm&1          & 29&\pm&3\\
    Text 3  & 8,16&\pm& 2,23    & 11,01&\pm&1,93\\
    Text 4  & 60&\pm& 14        & 148&\pm&8\\
    Text 5  & 90,7&\pm& 2,5     & 109,2&\pm&3,8\\
    Text 6  & 0,030&\pm& 0,008  & 0,034&\pm&0,004\\
    Text 7  & 5,72&\pm& 0,66    & 143,47&\pm&38,47 \\
    Text 8  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{--}  & (10,81&\pm&1,19)\times10^{5}\\
    Text 9  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{--}  & -12,95&\pm& 0,35\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `siunitx`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
   \begin{tabular}{rS[table-format=2.3(3)]S[%   
        table-format=-3.3(4)e1, 
        table-align-exponent = false, 
        table-space-text-post={)$\times 10^5$},
        table-space-text-pre={(},
        table-align-text-post=false,
        table-align-text-pre=false,
   ]}
    \toprule
    Text 1  & 6.58 +- 0.45    & 6.94 +- 0.51\\
    Text 2  & 25 +- 1         & 29 +- 3\\
    Text 3  & 8.16 +- 2.23    & 11.01 +- 1.93\\
    Text 4  & 60 +- 14        & 148 +- 8\\
    Text 5  & 90.7 +- 2.5     & 109.2 +- 3.8\\
    Text 6  & 0.030 +- 0.008  & 0.034 +- 0.004\\
    Text 7  & 5.72 +- 0.66    & 143.47 +- 38.47 \\
    Text 8  & {--}            & {(}10.81(119){)$\times 10^5$}\\% (10.81e5 +- 1.19e5)
    Text 9  & {--}            & -12.95 +- 0.35\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming one of the (typesetting) objectives is to align the uncertainty-component numbers on their decimal markers, the number "14" in the left-hand column of row 4 and the number "38,47" in the right-hand column of row 5 wouldn't see to be fully aligned. Can anything be done about this?

Comment: @Mico Yes, one could wait for v3, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85769/align-numbers-and-separated-uncertainties-in-tables-with-s-columns#comment185777_86218 or use your answer instead :)