# How do I align columns in a table with minus signs in math mode?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34614/in-a-tabular-how-to-left-align-ignoring-minus-signs), but that seems to specifically apply to center based on the decimal, and my table isn't numeric data. I'm trying to make the Cayley table for the quaternions, and a minimal working example for what my table looks like is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l|llllllll}
            $*$&$1$&$-1$&$i$&$-i$&$j$&$-j$&$k$&$-k$\\\hline
            $1$&$1$&$-1$&$i$&$-i$&$j$&$-j$&$k$&$-k$\\
            $-1$&$-1$&$1$&$-i$&$i$&$-j$&$j$&$-k$&$k$\\
            $i$&$i$&$-i$&$-1$&$1$&$k$&$-k$&$-j$&$j$\\
            $-i$&$-i$&$i$&$1$&$-1$&$-k$&$k$&$j$&$-j$\\
            $j$&$j$&$-j$&$-k$&$k$&$-1$&$1$&$i$&$-i$\\
            $-j$&$-j$&$j$&$k$&$-k$&$1$&$-1$&$-i$&$i$\\
            $k$&$k$&$-k$&$-j$&$j$&$-i$&$i$&$1$&$-1$\\
            $-k$&$-k$&$k$&$j$&$-j$&$i$&$-i$&$-1$&$1$\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output.

[image: bad Cayley table]

What I'd *like* for the table to look like is this:

[image: good Cayley table]

I'm sure that there's already a similar question on this site, but I couldn't find anything that applied to non-numeric cell values.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378290/align-elements-in-tabular-like-align-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost 100% sure there's better solutions, but you could use `\phantom{-}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l|llllllll}
            $*$ & $\phantom{-}1$ & $-1$ & $\phantom{-}i$ & $-i$ & $\phantom{-}j$ & $-j$ & $\phantom{-}k$ & $-k$ \\\hline
            $\phantom{-}1$ & $\phantom{-}1$ & $-1$ & $\phantom{-}i$ & $-i$ & $\phantom{-}j$ & $-j$ & $\phantom{-}k$ & $-k$ \\
            $-1$ & $-1$ & $\phantom{-}1$ & $-i$ & $\phantom{-}i$ & $-j$ & $\phantom{-}j$ & $-k$ & $\phantom{-}k$ \\
            $\phantom{-}i$ & $\phantom{-}i$ & $-i$ & $-1$ & $\phantom{-}1$ & $\phantom{-}k$ & $-k$ & $-j$ & $\phantom{-}j$ \\
            $-i$ & $-i$ & $\phantom{-}i$ & $\phantom{-}1$ & $-1$ & $-k$ & $\phantom{-}k$ & $\phantom{-}j$ & $-j$ \\
            $\phantom{-}j$ & $\phantom{-}j$ & $-j$ & $-k$ & $\phantom{-}k$ & $-1$ & $\phantom{-}1$ & $\phantom{-}i$ & $-i$ \\
            $-j$ & $-j$ & $\phantom{-}j$ & $\phantom{-}k$ & $-k$ & $\phantom{-}1$ & $-1$ & $-i$ & $\phantom{-}i$ \\
            $\phantom{-}k$ & $\phantom{-}k$ & $-k$ & $-j$ & $\phantom{-}j$ & $-i$ & $\phantom{-}i$ & $\phantom{-}1$ & $-1$ \\
            $-k$ & $-k$ & $\phantom{-}k$ & $\phantom{-}j$ & $-j$ & $\phantom{-}i$ & $-i$ & $-1$ & $\phantom{-}1$ \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Or, in this case, even just aligning the columns to the right might do (it does not produce the exact same output, though):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrrrrrr}
            $*$  & $1$  & $-1$ & $i$  & $-i$ & $j$  & $-j$ & $k$  & $-k$ \\\hline
            $1$  & $1$  & $-1$ & $i$  & $-i$ & $j$  & $-j$ & $k$  & $-k$ \\
            $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$  & $-i$ & $i$  & $-j$ & $j$  & $-k$ & $k$ \\
            $i$  & $i$  & $-i$ & $-1$ & $1$  & $k$  & $-k$ & $-j$ & $j$ \\
            $-i$ & $-i$ & $i$  & $1$  & $-1$ & $-k$ & $k$  & $j$  & $-j$ \\
            $j$  & $j$  & $-j$ & $-k$ & $k$  & $-1$ & $1$  & $i$  & $-i$ \\
            $-j$ & $-j$ & $j$  & $k$  & $-k$ & $1$  & $-1$ & $-i$ & $i$ \\
            $k$  & $k$  & $-k$ & $-j$ & $j$  & $-i$ & $i$  & $1$  & $-1$ \\
            $-k$ & $-k$ & $k$  & $j$  & $-j$ & $i$  & $-i$ & $-1$ & $1$ \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Also, [Math mode in tabular without having to use $...$ everywhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112576/math-mode-in-tabular-without-having-to-use-everywhere) might be of interest. All the best!

Comment: Oh yeah, right aligning the columns looks perfect!

Comment: Right-aligning the columns would probably look pretty good until you get a `$-m$`.  But here's a suggestion for a "shorthand'':  `\newcommand{\0}{\phantom{-}`.  Then a positive cell might contain `\01`.  The digits are left for use in temporary definitions, and since such a command can be only the one digit long, no space is wanted between it and what follows.

Comment: Oops!  The `\newcommand{\0){...}` that I suggested in an earlier comment is missing a final `}`.  (Sorry.)