# How to align numbers according to \pm but not according to the points?

Tags: tables

How to align numbers according to \pm but not according to the points? Each row should also have a different number of decimal places.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{}
\centering
\small
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = 5.4(1)]}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Parameter & Value \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip} 
A   & 26.5 \pm 2.0      \\
B   & 11.102 \pm 1.2 \\
C   & 53839  \pm 550 \\
D   & 0.5863     \pm 0.016 \\

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: `\pm` needs to be in math mode.

Comment: However, it is not necessary when it is a separation sign that should be aligned (siunitx package).

Comment: I think, in order to make `separate-uncertainty` work, you also need to set a `table-format` such as `table-format = 5.4(1)`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85769/align-numbers-and-separated-uncertainties-in-tables-with-s-columns

Comment: When I set the table format, it is aligned according to the decimal points as well. Same in the possible duplicate. I need to ignore decimal places.

Comment: Sorry, your problem was a bit unclear to me before. Thanks for adjuting the MWE so it actually shows your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86218/47927) suggests, the `S` column provided by the package `siunitx` only comes with certain alignment functions that primarily adjust numbers to the decimal separator, which is not what you want.

I therefore would suggest that you adjust the nice answer linked above and do the alignment manually without the use of the `siunitx` package. Since I don't know how you wish to align the numbers behind the `\pm` sign, I provide below two alternative solutions. I would also suggest to have a look at the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l r @{\,\( \pm \)\,} r }
\toprule
{Parameter} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value} \\
\midrule
A   & 26.5   & 2.0   \\
B   & 11.102 & 1.2   \\
C   & 53839  & 550   \\
D   & 0.5863 & 0.016 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ l r @{\,\( \pm \)\,} l }
\toprule
{Parameter} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value} \\
\midrule
A   & 26.5   & 2.0   \\
B   & 11.102 & 1.2   \\
C   & 53839  & 550   \\
D   & 0.5863 & 0.016 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of `siunitx` having implemented any feature to centre numbers around uncertainty markers. Perhaps it has and I don't know about it. The only workaround I can think of is to split numbers in two columns to get the effect. You could still use `siunitx` to let's say round numbers to some decimal places. Other than that, `siunitx` is not required

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\ustrut{\rule{0pt}{12pt}}
\newcommand\lstrut{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{12pt}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{
    round-mode=figures,
    round-precision=3,
    table-alignment-mode=none,
    separate-uncertainty,
  }
  \caption{}
  \centering
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{
      l
      S[table-number-alignment=right]
      @{\(\;\pm\;\)}
      S[table-number-alignment=left]
    }
    \hline\hline
    \ustrut Parameter & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value\lstrut}\\
    \hline\ustrut
    A   &   26.5 & 2.0 \\
    B   & 11.102 & 1.2 \\
    C   &  53839 & 550 \\
    D   & 0.5863 & 0.016 \lstrut \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```